# How to get values of several fields in a SELECT inside a STORED PROCEDURE

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, syntax, mysql-5.1

I am trying to populate my vars the following way.
Obviously, I am doing something wrong.

...

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE p_f1,p_f2 INT;
  SELECT
          f1 INTO p_f1,
          f2 INTO p_f2
  FROM
          t1
  LIMIT 1;
END
```

What is the proper syntax to populate p_f1 and p_f2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT
          f1,f2 
  INTO 
          p_f1,p_f2
  FROM
          t1
  LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You specify the INTO only once for the entire column/variable list.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE p_f1,p_f2 INT;
  SELECT
          f1, f2 INTO p_f1, p_f2
  FROM
          t1
  LIMIT 1;
END
```

As always, I'm a little concerned whenever I see a LIMIT used without an ORDER BY. Make sure you're consistently getting the same results every time by specifying an explicit order.

Comment: The specific query I really have, fetched only one result. Adding the LIMIT is just to stop the engine from continuing searching and in this question to make sure people see it returns only one record, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should do this

> BEGIN   DECLARE p_f1 t1.f1%Type, p_f2 t1.f2%Type;
>    SELEC1.f2%Type
>
> ```
>       f1,f2 into p_f1,
>       p_f2   FROM
>       t1   LIMIT 1; END
> ```